# animation for revealing a nested table w/ javaScript using .slideToggle

Tags: javascript

New to javascript (and front end in general) here, so forgive my mistakes.

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMux/EZthV/1/), I have a nested table I want to reveal on clicking the triangle. I want to give the transition a little animation rather than just popping open. Here is my code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".second").hide();
    $("a").click(function(e)
        {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        var tr = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td').find(".triangle")
        .toggleClass("collapse")
        .toggleClass("expand");
        var tableId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
        $(tableId).slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });
```

Any assistance on how to give the reveal some animation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you never selected to use jQuery in JSFiddle